# LeetCode expects null instead of None. How to do this in python?

Tags: python, list, binary-search-tree

I'm currently working on LeetCode problem [108. Convert Sorted Array to Binary Search Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/convert-sorted-array-to-binary-search-tree/):

> Given an integer array `nums` where the elements are sorted in **ascending order**, convert *it to a **height-balanced** binary search tree*.
>
> A **height-balanced** binary tree is a binary tree in which the depth of the two subtrees of every node never differs by more than one.

My code seems to be working fine but I don't know how to display the value *null* instead of *None* in my list. I need to print the BST in level order traversal. I'm looking for advice, hints or suggestions.

Input:

```
[-10,-3,0,5,9]
```

My current output:

```
[0, -3, 9, -10, None, 5, None]
```

Accepted output:

```
[0,-3,9,-10,null,5]
```

Here is my code:

```
from queue import Queue
from typing import Optional

class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def sortedArrayToBST(nums: [int]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
    nbNodes = len(nums)

    if nbNodes == 1:
        root = TreeNode()
        root.val = nums[0]
        return root
    elif nbNodes == 0:
        root = TreeNode()
        root.val = None
        return root

    middle = int(nbNodes / 2)
    root = TreeNode()
    root.val = nums[middle]
    leftList = []
    rightList = []
    j = middle + 1

    for i in range(middle):
        leftList.append(nums[i])

        if j != nbNodes:
            rightList.append(nums[j])
        j += 1

    root.left = sortedArrayToBST(leftList)
    root.right = sortedArrayToBST(rightList)
    return root

def levelorder(root):
    if root==None:
        return
    Q=Queue()
    Q.put(root)
    level_order_list = []
    while(not Q.empty()):
        node=Q.get()
        if node==None:
            continue
        level_order_list.append(node.val)
        Q.put(node.left)
        Q.put(node.right)
    print(level_order_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    container = [-10,-3,0,5,9]
    levelorder(sortedArrayToBST(container))
```

Comment: What do you want `null` to be? A string? something else? Python doesn't have a `null` type backed in, it has a `None` instead.

Comment: I'm doing a problem on LeetCode, and the expected output is written with a null value in the list: ` [0,-3,9,-10, null,5]`. I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a weird requirement that has nothing to do with the apparent main point of the problem and I suspect it's a result of the description being copied over from one that's aimed at another language (like Javascript, which uses `null` instead of `None`).

You can, however, format your list however you like when you print it; here's an example where we print a list by joining each item with `","` (instead of the default `", "`) and replace `None` with `"null"`:

```
>>> my_list = [0, -3, 9, -10, None, 5, None]
>>> print("[" + ",".join("null" if i is None else str(i) for i in my_list) + "]")
[0,-3,9,-10,null,5,null]
```

Since JSON renders `None` as `null`, another option would be to dump the list to JSON and remove the `" "` characters:

```
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps(my_list).replace(' ', ''))
[0,-3,9,-10,null,5,null]
```

Comment: It worked. I just needed to write it as a string

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to `null` or `None`. LeetCode is a platform for taking code challenges in many different languages and they use JSON style to describe input/output, and in JSON notation `None` translates to `null`.

Not to worry about *that*. However, when you look at your output, there is a trailing `None` that should not be there. That means that you returned a BST that has a node with a `None` value. This should not happen.

The code that creates this `None` valued node is easy to identify... it is here:

```
    elif nbNodes == 0:
        root = TreeNode()
        root.val = None
        return root
        return
```

When you think of it, this cannot be right: the *number* of nodes to generate (`nbNodes`) is 0, yet your code creates 1 node -- and that is one too many! In this case you should just return `None` to indicate that the parent node has no child here.

So replace with:

```
    elif nbNodes == 0:
        return
```

This fixes the issue you mentioned, and your code will now pass all tests on LeetCode.

Here is your code with the above corrections and with the `self` parameter restored (which you had removed to run it without the need to create a class instance):

```
class Solution:
    def sortedArrayToBST(self, nums: List[int]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        nbNodes = len(nums)

        if nbNodes == 1:
            root = TreeNode()
            root.val = nums[0]
            return root
        elif nbNodes == 0:
            return

        middle = int(nbNodes / 2)
        root = TreeNode()
        root.val = nums[middle]
        leftList = []
        rightList = []
        j = middle + 1

        for i in range(middle):
            leftList.append(nums[i])

            if j != nbNodes:
                rightList.append(nums[j])
            j += 1

        root.left = self.sortedArrayToBST(leftList)
        root.right = self.sortedArrayToBST(rightList)
        return root
```

### Other improvements

Unrelated to your question, but there are several things you can optimise:

- Try to avoid creating new lists (`leftList`, `rightList`): copying values into them takes time and space. Instead use start/end indices in the original list to denote which sublist is currently processed.
- Make use of the additional arguments you can pass to the `TreeNode` constructor. That way you don't have to assign to attributes *after* the constructor has run.
- Use the integer division operator instead of the floating point division operator.
- One of the two base cases is not needed as it would be dealt with correctly by the next recursive calls.

Here is a spoiler solution that applies those remarks:

> `class Solution:
>      def sortedArrayToBST(self, nums: List[int]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
>          def recur(start: int, end: int):
>              if start < end:
>                  middle = (start + end) // 2
>                  return TreeNode(nums[middle],
>                                  recur(start, middle),
>                                  recur(middle + 1, end))
>          return recur(0, len(nums))`

Comment: I did modify my code and now pass all tests, but when I submitted my code, there is one test that I cannot pass. Strangely, I'm able to pass this test on PyCharm and LeetCode before submitting. Should I do another post to ask my question? @trincot

Comment: Yes, because I actually submitted the code on LeetCode and it *did* pass all tests, so you must have made a mistake somewhere (of course, I had to adapt your function and re-introduce the `self` parameter and align the recursive calls with that -- maybe you forgot that?)

Comment: I added the full LeetCode-compatible code at the end of my answer. I just submitted it again -- passes.

Comment: Thank you! No, I didn't forget the self parameter. It was just easier to work without it in PyCharm. So, my mistake was with the base case when the list is empty, so `len(nums) = 0`. Outside of that would you say that my code is efficient? What would you say is the biggest flaw in my code? What would you change? Thank you very much! @trincot

Comment: See addition to my answer.

Comment: Did that addition answer your comments on efficiency, biggest flaw, potential changes? Anything else that needs clarification?